# Regenerate Thumbnails and moving site to a new server

Tags: wordpress

I used the regenerate thumbnail plugin to do exactly that when I was designed my site. I since have finished the site and ready to move the site to a new hosting provider/server. I downloaded the files from the server via FTP. I noticed that it also downloaded all of the various image sizes that were created from the regenerate thumbnail plugin.

My question. When I upload the site to the new server, will the images be included into the media library and show all the different sizes of that one image? Or will it only show the main image like I have on the site I designed the Wordpress site on.

I just don't want the media library to show thousands of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will just show single main image in media library. Not all different size of images of a single image in media library.